# how to make a map from some lists with lambdas?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, lambda, java-8

Hello friends I have the following problem, I am just using java 8 so I am struggling to do the following.

Make the following interface

```
public interface AbstracConvert <T,M>{
    public M fromMap(T tupla, List<String> keys);
    
    public default List<M> fromMap(List<T> tuplas, List<String> keys){
        return tuplas.stream().map(e-> fromMap(e,keys)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And the following implementation

```
@Component
public class TupleConvert  implements AbstracConvert<Tuple, Map<String, Object>>{

@Override


public Map<String, Object> fromMap(Tuple tupla, List<String> keys) {

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("name", tupla.get("name_build"));
        response.put("idDir", tupla.get("id_dir"));
        return response;
        
    }

}
```

The basic idea is to be able to transform a list of tuples to a list of maps, this to be able to show it within the response however, in my implementation what I am doing is knowing the aliases of the query elements and putting them in a map resulting in the following response

```
{
   "name" : "name1",
    "idDir" : 3
},

{
   "name" : "name2",
    "idDir" : 4

} ....
```

I want to improve my method by sending a list with the values of the map keys and entering each of its values according to another list with the aliases, this in order to make it a little more generic

I have the following in my @Service

```
@Service
public class TestAppImpl implements TestApp {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestJpaDao testJpaDao;

    @Autowired
    private TupleConvert convert;

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> find(String query) {
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        keys.add("name");
        keys.add("idDir");
        
        return convert.fromMap(testJpaDao.execute(query), keys);
    }
}
```

and within my class

```
@Component
public class TupleConvert  implements AbstracConvert<Tuple, Map<String, Object>>{

@Override
public Map<String, Object> fromMap(Tuple tupla, List<String> keys) {
    
    List<String> alias = tupla.getElements().stream().map(t->t.getAlias()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    result= keys.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(*keys list value* , *tuple value according to alias list*));
    
    return result;
    
}
}
```

what I want to do is be able to make a map with the keys of a treeset and the values according to a method by iterating a list of strings.

the value of the key is different from the busy alias for the get method, that's why I get a list with the alias values

```
     @Override
        public Map<String, Object> fromMap(Tuple tuple, TreeSet<String> keys) {

List<String> alias = tuple.getElements().stream().map(t-> t.getAlias()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   
    return keys.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),t-> t.get(alias.stream().reduce((first,second) -> second).map((String x)-> x).orElse(null)));
        }
    }
```

if I do this it returns the map but with the last value obtained from the list of aliases

```
{

“var1”: “hehejej”,

“var2”: “hehejej”,

“var3” :“hehejej”

}
```

my list of keys makes it this way

```
TreeSet<String> keys = new TreeSet();
keys.add(“var1”);
keys.add(“var2”);
keys.add(“var3”);
```

what I want to achieve is that for each key the value obtained from the get method is assigned, por example

```
{

“var1”: 36467,

“var2”: 122,

“var3”: “hehejej”

}
```

Comment: Can you also post the content of `Tuple` class/interface?

Comment: You should show a complete example with its input and desired output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as the name of your `keys` parameter imply it is a collection of keys so it should not have repetitive value so it is better to declare it as `Set` and not `List`, second you may access to elements of your `Tuple` by key, if you have, the problem is solved like below:

```
public class TupleConvert  implements AbstracConvert<Tuple, Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> fromMap(Tuple tuple, Set<String> keys) {
        return keys.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), tuple::getByKey));
    }
}
```

If you don't have, you may have method like `getValue` on `Element` in `Tuple` then you can achieve it like below:

```
public class TupleConvert  implements AbstracConvert<Tuple, Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> fromMap(Tuple tuple, Set<String> keys) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        return tuple.getElements().stream().filter(t -> keys.contains(t.getAlias()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Element::getAlias, Element::getValue));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I already did something, I know what you mention, however I have problems, I have updated the question